# Django rest framework datetime field format

Tags: ios, django, swift, django-rest-framework

I use this field:

```
ordered_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="iso-8601", required=False, read_only=True)
```

and when i go to rest url, i get time:

```
"ordered_date": "2015-10-22T19:50:08"
```

but when i serialize date and then send it with GCM push, it adds miliseconds(`2015-10-22T19:53:43.777171`), how can i fix this, i need only one format to use, not mix with these two.

How can i fix this?

I use this for ios swift app.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can specify a `format` parameter to the `ordered_date` field having value as a string representing the output format.

```
ordered_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", required=False, read_only=True)
```

**For example:**

```
In [1]: from rest_framework import  serializers

In [2]: from datetime import datetime

In [3]: class XYZSerializer(serializers.Serializer): # define a serializer with a datetime field
   ...:     ordered_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
   ...:    

In [4]: x = XYZSerializer(data={'ordered_date':datetime.now()})

In [5]: x.is_valid()
Out[5]: True

In [6]: x.data # contains the datetime field in the desired format
Out[6]: OrderedDict([('ordered_date', '2015-10-22T18:17:51')])
```

Comment: @user1362215 Please provide a code example for the above.

Comment: You can also set global defaults in your `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings with `DATETIME_FORMAT` (format returned by API) and `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` (list of formats accepted by API).

Answer (score 19):

Thanks to @Red-Tune-84's comment
I customize the format of all my datetimefields.

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    ....
}
```